# Cannot execute batch class from a managed beta?

Tags: batch, beta-managed-package

My project has a batch class. Before I package my project into a managed beta, I test I can run the batch class from the Developer console.

```
My_Batch b = new My_Batch();
Database.executeBatch(b);
```

Everything runs.

However, when I install this managed beta into a new org and try the same code from a developer console, I get:

```
Invalid type: My_Batch
```

What is not ok to run the batch class from the managed beta?
Is there any other way I can run it?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to prefix the My_Batch with the namespacesprefix of the package: `[namespace].My_Batch b = new [namespace].My_Batch();` or `[namespace]__My_Batch b = new [namespace]__My_Batch();`

Comment: @Lex [namespace].My_Batch b = new [namespace].My_Batch(); works.  Thanks. I'll accept it as answer.

Comment: Great! I've created an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to prefix the `My_Batch` with the namespacesprefix of the package: `[namespace].My_Batch b = new [namespace].My_Batch();`